# Не работает обработка нажатия Enter с клавиатуры. Обрабатываются только цифры

Tags: java, android, клавиатура, listener, обработка

Находил несколько примеров по этому поводу, где то со switch где то c if, но суть не в этом, так и так не работает. Обработчик реагирует только на нажатия цифр. Даже default в switch`e не реагирует. Что я делаю не так? Вот код

```
edit.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN == event.getAction()){
                switch (keyCode){
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
                        Log.e("TAG", "Нажат интер");
                        break;
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_2:
                        Log.e("TAG", "Нажато 2");
                        break;
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_E:
                        Log.e("TAG", "Нажато e");
                        break;
                    default: Log.e("TAG", "Нажато что то");
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Весь обработчик реагирует только на цифры. Нажимаю буквы или какие нибудь другие символы default не срабатывает, нажимаю цифры кроме 2 - срабатывает. Нажимаю 2 - работает. Все клавиши перетыкал "Нажато е" не выходит. И интер тоже. Может дело в модели телефона не знаю, у меня Lenovo S650 Андроид 4.4.2 Api 19. Другого телефона нет для проверки.

Comment: А в XML полю вводу, случаем, никакого фильтра не назначено?..

Comment: нет фильтра никакого нет, у EditText`a только id, ширина, высота и всё

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OnKeyListener` работает криво и в основном только как раз для цифр с кейпада, остальные клавиши не воспринимает. Странно при этом, что ентер тоже не работает. В этом случае лучше использовать `TextWatcher`, как-то так:

```
myTextView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
             if (s.subSequence(count-1,count).equals("нужная кнопка"))
                ...выполнить нужное действие
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```