# Обработка нажатия на ENTER

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

Я уже спрашивал это [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/516187/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F-enter-%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D1%8B), но немного не понял и появились еще вопросы по этому поводу.

На клаве стоит кнопка ENTER - со стрелкой, которая переносит на новую строку и именно такая мне нужна и именно такая не обрабатывается, не реагирует.

В общем работает со всеми видами интера, только не с тем, которая мне нужна. Почему именно она не работает? Так и должно быть? Или я что то не так делаю. И как это сделать? Делал `KeyListener'ом`, `OnEditorActionListenerом` - всё тоже самое.

**Код** вот. В разметке у эдита обычные `id` , ширина и высота.

```
edit.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN == event.getAction()){
                switch (keyCode){
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
                        Log.e("TAG", "Нажат интер");
                        break;
                    default: Log.e("TAG", "Нажато что то");
                }
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Насчет `TextWatcher`, не знаю как им сделать то, что мне нужно. Если `keyListener`ом нельзя то объясните пожалуйста как делать через `TextWatcher`.
В предыдущем примере по ссылке написано "нужная кнопка" и в общем не понял как туда вставлять ENTER.

Задача такая, нужно получить первую строку в `EditText`, определяется она по кнопке ENTER. То есть написали что то, нажали ENTER и это первая строка. Курсор на новой строке, печатаем дальше. Строки разделяются кнопкой ENTER. Получить ее можно как я понял split`ом.

Это я рассказал, чтобы было понятно о чем я. Я новичок.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал. Получил первую строчку `edittext'а`. Не обрабатывая ENTER, Код

```
edit.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            if (!s.toString().contains("\n")){
                Log.e("TAG", "Первая строка: Печатается");
            }else {
                String[] str = s.toString().split("\n");
                Log.e("TAG", "Первая строка: " + str[0]);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Enter на "нужная кнопка" не прописывается, да.
Если нужен именно Enter, попробуйте так: (пример взят [отсюда](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/ui/controls/text.html))

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myEditText);
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
      if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
          ...ваши действия
          return true;
      }
    return false;
    }
});
```

в самом EditText (в xml) надо выставить `android:imeOptions = "done"` (или более подходящий).

Comment: На "нужная кнопка" не знаю как вставить нужную кнопку. `.equals(String.valueOf(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)))`  И конечно не сработало

Comment: И на enter типа done да работает, просто тогда клавиатура сразу закрывается и не переносится на новую строку.  Можно сделать, чтобы не закрывалась и думаю можно сделать ,чтобы переносилась. Но думаю нельзя вставить картинку со стрелкой , как в оригинальном интере вместо надписи "готово"

Comment: попробуйте в imeOptions прописать что-то другое, например "actionNone". `TextWatcher` ентер не обрабатывает)

Comment: Нет, не работает(

Comment: Можно в `TextWatcher` отловить перенос строки? с помощью /n. А точнее как это сделать)

Comment: чо-т вроде нет. Вообще, ентер в OnKey должен бы ловиться...

Comment: Да, стоит сказать, что на Samsung всё работает замечательно и без `TextWather'а`, но у меня Lenovo

Answer (score 0):

Была такая же проблема, использовал тоже TextWatcher

```
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (chooseCity.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
                return;
            }
            if (s.toString().contains("\n")) {
                chooseCity.setText(s.toString().replace('\n', ' ').trim());
                hideSoftKeyboard(getApplicationContext());
            }
        }
```